# Adding a Column to CSV Using Data Returned From Function

Tags: function, powershell, csv, formatting

I've been working on a script that takes output from a syslog server containing firewall logs, re-organizes that output to a new CSV file in a more readable format, and then performs a lookup on the source IP addresses to identify what city traffic originates from. **I'm not sure how to get the results from my function that looks up details on the IP addresses to add additional columns to the new CSV file.**

This is an example of a single record from the source file. Note: I've edited the IP addresses to mask them.

> 2018-07-01 14:48:47,Local7.Info,192.168.1.00,device="SFW"
>   date=2018-07-01 time=14:48:39 timezone="PDT" device_name="XG"
>   device_id=00000000000000 log_id=010101600001 log_type="Firewall"
>   log_component="Firewall Rule" log_subtype="Allowed" status="Allow"
>   priority=Information duration=11 fw_rule_id=3 policy_type=3
>   user_name="" user_gp="" iap=0 ips_policy_id=0 appfilter_policy_id=0
>   application="Secure Socket Layer Protocol" application_risk=1
>   application_technology="Network Protocol"
>   application_category="Infrastructure" in_interface="Port2"
>   out_interface="Port1" src_mac=00: 0:00: 0:00: 0 src_ip=75.148.000.000
>   src_country_code=USA dst_ip=23.24.000.000 dst_country_code=USA
>   protocol="TCP" src_port=55000 dst_port=443 sent_pkts=7 recv_pkts=6
>   sent_bytes=1369 recv_bytes=918 tran_src_ip=192.168.000.000
>   tran_src_port=0 tran_dst_ip=192.168.000.000 tran_dst_port=0
>   srczonetype="WAN" srczone="WAN" dstzonetype="LOCAL" dstzone="LOCAL"
>   dir_disp="" connevent="Stop" connid="1782869248" vconnid=""
>   hb_health="No Heartbeat" message="" appresolvedby="Signature"

With the help of other users on here, I've been able to write a script that creates a new CSV file (**$output_file**) with a more reader-friendly format, and looks up information on the **src_ip** column. I'm not sure how I can take the results from that function (**Get-IPGeolocation**) and add additional columns to my **$output_file** with the results.

```
#Parameters for environment
$regex = '\b(\w+)=([^ ]+)'
$input_path = "C:\powershell_work\ParsingSophos\data.csv"
$output_file = "C:\powershell_work\GeolocatingIPs\combine-output.csv"


#Function used to lookup IP-Address information.
function Get-IPGeolocation
{
    Param
    (
        [string]$IPAddress
    )

    $request = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri "http://geoip.nekudo.com/api/$IPAddress"

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        IP        = $request.IP
        City      = $request.City
        Country   = $request.Country.Name
        Code      = $request.Country.Code
        Location  = $request.Location.Latitude
        Longitude = $request.Location.Longitude
        TimeZone  = $request.Location.Time_zone
    }
}

# Parsing the input_path file, and exporting to a more workable format
Select-String -LiteralPath $input_path -AllMatches -Pattern $regex | ForEach-Object {
    $obj = New-Object pscustomobject
    foreach ($match in $_.Matches) {
      Add-Member -InputObject $obj -NotePropertyName $match.Groups[1].Value -NotePropertyValue $match.Groups[2].Value
    }
    $obj
} | Select-Object *_ip, srczone, src_country_code, dstzone, dst_country_code | 
     Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation $output_file


# Gathering list of Source IPs to be used in the lookup
$src_ips = Import-CSV $output_file | select -ExpandProperty src_ip


# Loop that runs each IP through the function to find IP address information
ForEach($ip in $src_ips) {
Get-IPGeolocation -IPAddress $ip
}
```

Running that script with multiple records of data in your **$input_path** CSV file returns results like this.
[Output Exmaple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmJEJ.png)

Comment: There is IMO nothing wrong. PowerShell switches output to Format-List view if the number of columns/width exceeds a limits. Try piping to `| Format-Table -Auto`

Comment: `Get-Help about_Preference_Variables` lookup `$FormatEnumerationLimit` default=4

Comment: @LotPings That is what I told em last time this question was asked. Also I don't think `$FormatEnumerationLimit` helps here since that should be for arrays in columns no?

Comment: How would I get the data returned from the function "Get-IPGeolocation" to create new columns back into the CSV file  $output_file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In essence, you're asking **how to merge two custom objects**:

A simple example (PSv4+ syntax, assumes that the property-name sets don't overlap):

```powershell
# Create two sample custom objects to merge.
$co1 = [pscustomobject] @{ one = 1; two = 2; three = 3 }
$co2 = [pscustomobject] @{ four = 4; five = 5; six = 6 }

# Add $co2's properties to $co1
$co2.psobject.properties.foreach({
  Add-Member -InputObject $co1 -NotePropertyName $_.Name -NotePropertyValue $_.Value
})

# Output $co1, which now contains its own properties plus the ones from $co2.
$co1
```

The above yields:

```powershell
one   : 1
two   : 2
three : 3
four  : 4
five  : 5
six   : 6
```

---

Applied to your scenario:

```powershell
Import-Csv $output_file | ForEach-Object {
  $obj = $_
  (Get-IPGeolocation -IPAddress $obj.src_ip).psobject.properties.foreach({
    Add-Member -InputObject $obj -NotePropertyName $_.Name -NotePropertyValue $_.Value
  })
  $obj
} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation .\merged.csv
```

Comment: @FrameWorkTeam: My pleasure; glad to hear it was helpful.